# Flutter [first app] crashes on android studio and vscode

Tags: android, flutter, mobile, visual-studio-code

i am trying flutter for the first time..
i have no problems with flutter doctor so i created my first app in vscode
and i tried to run it on the emulator but it fails every time!
I uninstalled sdk and install it again, plus i have updated all path and variables..
I cant find a solution so any help would be nice!
Thanks in advance!!!!

Here is the error messages

```
 Launching lib\main.dart on Google Nexus 5 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:53362/6fXjiT0oaKk=/ws
Syncing files to device Google Nexus 5...
F/libc    ( 1438): Fatal signal 4 (SIGILL) at 0x94857d41 (code=2), thread 1455 (1.raster)
*** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:4.4.4/KTU84P/630:userdebug/test-keys'
Revision: '0'
pid: 1438, tid: 1455, name: 1.raster  >>> com.example.my_app <<<
signal 4 (SIGILL), code 2 (ILL_ILLOPN), fault addr 94857d41
    eax 934ead30  ebx 95106040  ecx 934e9f80  edx 00000000
    esi 00000018  edi 00000002
    xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b
    eip 94857d41  ebp 934e9ec8  esp 934e9e80  flags 00210246
backtrace:
    #00  pc 000c2d41  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #01  pc 000c25d7  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #02  pc 000c294c  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #03  pc 000cbb01  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #04  pc 000e1c57  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #05  pc 000e30ee  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #06  pc 000e2682  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #07  pc 000e2c7b  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #08  pc 000f293a  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #09  pc 000f2879  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #10  pc 000f2c0f  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #11  pc 000f2de4  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #12  pc 00098f84  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #13  pc 0009934c  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #14  pc 0007a19a  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #15  pc 000f0866  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #16  pc 000a5ec5  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #17  pc 000eef25  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #18  pc 000ef063  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #19  pc 000fd416  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #20  pc 000fd348  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #21  pc 000fd482  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #22  pc 00293149  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #23  pc 002933a7  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #24  pc 0024722d  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #25  pc 0025405d  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #26  pc 00214c05  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #27  pc 0021bd79  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #28  pc 002091bc  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #29  pc 00208f34  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #30  pc 002094a4  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    #31  pc 00225d4a  /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
memory map around fault addr 94857d41:
    935ec000-94795000 r-- /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    94795000-94fde000 r-x /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
    94fde000-950bd000 rw- /data/app-lib/com.example.my_app-1/libflutter.so
Lost connection to device.
```

Comment: Can you try on a AVD ?

Comment: Have you checked flutter doctor for any issues? The command is: `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: Yes i checked flutter doctor and evertything is fine..